# How to convert HTTP Request Body into JSON Object in Java

Tags: java, json, http, sling

I am trying find a Java lib/api that will allow me to turn the contents of a HTTP Request POST body into a JSON object.

Ideally I would like to use a [Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org/site/index.html) library (as they are exposed in my container naturally).

The closest I've found it: `org.apache.sling.commons.json.http` which converts the header to JSON.

HTTP Post bodies are in the format; `key1=value1&key2=value2&..&keyn=valueN` so I assume there is something out there, but I havent been able to find it.

I may just have to use a custom `JSONTokener` (`org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONTokener`) to do this if something doesn't already exist. Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're using an [HttpServlet](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) and a JSON library like [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) you could do something like this:

```js
public JSONObject requestParamsToJSON(ServletRequest req) {
  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
  Map<String,String[]> params = req.getParameterMap();
  for (Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry : params.entrySet()) {
    String v[] = entry.getValue();
    Object o = (v.length == 1) ? v[0] : v;
    jsonObj.put(entry.getKey(), o);
  }
  return jsonObj;
}
```

With example usage:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
  JSONObject jsonObj = requestParamsToJSON(req);
  // Now "jsonObj" is populated with the request parameters.
  // e.g. {"key1":"value1", "key2":["value2a", "value2b"], ...}
}
```

Comment: turns out you can do: JSONObject json = new JSONObject(slingHttpServletRequest.getParameterMap()); as well - your method does give a bit more control over what is allowed into the json object (such as introducing a white/black list) - which is nice.

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded JSON library from the link you have provided above. How can I use it now. can you please mention it??

Comment: @empire29 : More insights on it are very much appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson is also a good option - its used extensively in Spring.  Here is the tutorial: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Comment: It won't help turning URL params into JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying [Apache Commons Beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/).

```
ServeltRequest request;

Map map = request.getParameterMap();
MyObject object = new MyObject();
BeanUtils.populate(object, map);
String json = object.toJSON() //using any JSON library
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry on making this an own answer but obviously my reputation doesn't allow me to simply add a comment to the answer [How to convert HTTP Request Body into JSON Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085545/how-to-convert-http-request-body-into-json-object-in-java/7085652#7085652) of maerics.

I would also iterate over the request params but instead of using an arbitrary json library use the JSONObject that is provided by sling. http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/commons/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 1):

**import org.json.JSONObject;**

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(request.getParameterMap())
```

Comment: every value is an array

Answer (score -1):

Use Gson. With this you can create class with private variables which represent the data you want : for example.

```
meta:{
       name:"Example"
       firstname:"Example2"
     }
data:[
      {
        title:"ecaetra"
        description:"qwerty"
      }
      ...
     ]
```

Json Object could be retrieve like this :

```
public class RetrieveData {

      private Meta meta;
      private List<Data> data;

      public Meta getMeta(){
            return meta;
      }

      public List<Data> getData(){
            return data;
      }
}

public class Meta {

      private String name;
      private String firstname;

      public String getName(){
            return name;
      }

      public String getFirstName(){
            return firstname;
      }

}

public class Data {

      private String title;
      private String description;

      public String getTitle(){
            return title;
      }

      public String getDescription(){
            return description;
      }

}
```

And your instruction are simple. Content is the content of your Page, you can retrieve it with Asynctask.

```
 Object o = new Gson().fromJson(Content, RetrieveData.class);
 data = (RetrieveData)o;
 // Get Meta
    data.getName(); // Example
    data.getFirstName(); // Example2
 // Get Data
    data.get(0).getTitle(); // position 0 : ecaetra
    data.get(0).getDescription(); // position 0 : qwerty
```