# create json object from request body which contains JSON data

Tags: java, json

My request body contains JSON. i have to read that JSON save it as JSON object. And i don't have any pojo class representing the data in json. i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085545/how-to-convert-http-request-body-into-json-object-in-java) , [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085545/how-to-convert-http-request-body-into-json-object-in-java) and i am using com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject.i have tried this ,

```
BufferedReader ne = req.getReader();

    StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
      BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        jb.append(line);
    } catch (Exception e) { /*report an error*/ }

      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
      jsonObject.put("data", jb.toString());
```

above implementation is dumb because i am converting request header to string and adding it to jsonobject.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `public static JSONObject parse( java.lang.String str)` in class JSONObject .Also there is no need to convert Reader to String as there are overloaded methods in JSONObject which take Inputstream and Reader eg  `public static JSONObject parse( java.io.Reader reader)`